# Tocloft - change listof title format individually, while using titles option

Tags: table-of-contents, titles, tocloft

I defined some new listofs with the `tocloft` package and used the provided `titles` option, but I only want the ToC to look like one of my chapters. My custom listofs should look like sections without numbers (`\section*`). Is there a way to change the format of certain titles of listofs while using the `titles` option?

```
\documentclass[twosite]{scrbook}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\newlistof[chapter]{som}{exp}{List of Something}
\newcommand{\something}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{som}
   \par\noindent{Som.\hspace{1ex}\thesom:\hspace{1em}#1}
   \addcontentsline{exp}{som}{\textbf{Som.\hspace{1ex}\protect\numberline{\thesom}:} #1}\par
}
\begin{document}
   \something{Something is more than nothing}
   \listofsom
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly: You want to have a section like ToC header for your `\listofsom` command?

Comment: Yes, I want the header for the `\listofsom` command to look and work like a normal section.

Comment: Please have a look on my possible solution

Comment: By the way, the `twosite` option should read `twoside` ;-)

Comment: Hmm, why does it work then? :-)

Comment: Unknown options are ignored ... `twosite` is unknown. Is it ok to delete the `miktex` tag ... it has nothing to do with your question

Comment: Sure! I meant: `twosite` works exactly the same like `twoside`. It also changes every second page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure about the real question, but this provides a `\section*` style heading for the custom `\listofsom`  command.

`\listof...` usually use a `\chapter*` command when used in conjunction with the `book.cls` (or `scrbook.cls`). Using `xpatch` package and its `\xpatchcmd` it's easy to replace the `\chapter*` command in the definition of `\listof...` by `section*`.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\newlistof[chapter]{som}{exp}{List of Something}

\newcommand{\something}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{som}
   \par\noindent{Som.\hspace{1ex}\thesom:\hspace{1em}#1}
   \addcontentsline{exp}{som}{\textbf{Som.\hspace{1ex}\protect\numberline{\thesom}:} #1}\par
}


\xpatchcmd{\listofsom}{\chapter*}{\section*}{}{}

\begin{document}
   \tableofcontents
   \chapter{First}

   \something{Something is more than nothing}
   \noindent Now the list of somethings 
   \listofsom
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted, thanks for your fast response!